# how to pass integers and list of strings and retrieve them as parameters in AWS Batch using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, etl, aws-batch

For my AWS batch job I would like to pass multiple parameters like height, width, and a list of strings when I submit the batch job and retrieve them inside my program.

I would like to pass these values as parameters to submit_job.

```
parameters = {
            'width': 320,
            'height': 240,
            'aspect_ratio': 1.78,
            'image_format': ['.jpg', '.png']
        }

        response = batch.submit_job(
            jobName=jobName,
            jobQueue=job_queue,
            jobDefinition=job_def,
            parameters=parameters
        )
```

this is how interpret it inside my program.

```
width= sys.argv[0]
height=sys.argv[1]
aspect_ratio = sys.argv[2]
image_format = sys.argv[3]
```

this is how I defined my run command.
`["python","./script.py", "Ref::width", "Ref::height"]`

The error I get is ""Error submitting job: Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter parameters.width, value: 340, type: <class 'int'>, valid types: <class 'str'>